# accessing the printer connected on the local network via wifi in android

Tags: android, android-wifi, printers

In the Lan connected printer, I want to print the files in sd card of the android device 
so, i want to access that printer through wifi not withe the ip address of the printer.
I spent much time on googling, but i didn't find any solution.

Can anybody help me in this issue. For any help Thanks a lot in Advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should use cloud to print technology of google for getting printer of your local network.

[Cloud to print by google](http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/)

[application link of android market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pauloslf.cloudprint&hl=en)

[Api for printing doc in Andorid](http://android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/140-api-for-printing-from-android-applications)

Comment: for cloud users have to register the printer with google cloud servers right? and for Api the send 2 printer has to be install on the device from android market right? if these two are right then suggest me other way please its urgent

Comment: no but its require eamil id of user please use the application i hope you get understanding through it.

Comment: email id of user means his gmail account mailid or what

Comment: any response will print on logcat that the printing is successful?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12228/discussion-between-dynamicmind-and-user1108995)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to print to a big desktop printer or a receipt printer?

If you're looking for a receipt printer, Star Micronics has an Android SDK that you can freely download here: http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx.

It covers LAN printing along with USB and bluetooth.

This SDK has a really nice sample app that lets you test and customize a lot of printer functions to see them in action. Each function is documented in the source code. The commands and their parameters are also available in the app itself as a quick on screen reference which is convenient. On top of all that, it's well documented.

If you use their SDK, you can send plain text to the printer along with commands. The API handles converting the data into what the printer can understand.

Comment: thanks for the reply LtH , but i didn't find any java code to execute the starIO jar, can you please tell me the clear way to do please i spent a lot of time

Comment: Import their sample app into eclipse, open StarIOSDKActivity.java, and run from there. Check out the manuals that came in the package.. the POS printer manual has instructions for importing on page 8.